# Calling method don't execute rest of the code

Tags: java, android

I have a thread running that calls draw method from class1 which calls another draw method from class2 (draw method of class2 posted below).

The draw method of class2 runs a bit of code and draw circles, and calls a method called drawtext. In the drawText method, it calls a method calls calculation before canvas.drawText but the rest of drawText method(codes of canvas.drawText) don't get executed.

How is this possible? I thought when method is called, it's just called without interrupting the "parent method"..

Thanks!

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    double HEIGHT = customView.HEIGHT;
    double WIDTH = customView.WIDTH;
    double margin = customView.margin;
    r = WIDTH / 2 - margin;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double randX = getRN();
        double randY = getRN();
        if (Math.hypot(randX - r, randY - r) > r) {
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            count++;
        }
        //System.out.println(randX + " " + randY + " " + WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT);
        //System.out.println((randX + margin) + " " + (HEIGHT / 2 - WIDTH / 2 + randY));
        canvas.drawCircle((float) (randX + margin), (float) (randY + HEIGHT / 2 - r), 10, paint);
        total++;
    }
    drawText(canvas);
}

public void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    calculate();
    canvas.drawText("Valid / Total: " + count + " / " + total + "  (" + ratioPercentage + ")", 75, 91, paint);
    /*BigDecimal countBig = new BigDecimal(count);
    BigDecimal totalBig = new BigDecimal(total);
    BigDecimal piCalculated = (countBig.divide(totalBig)).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(4));*/
    canvas.drawText("Calculated \u03C0 : " + piCalculated, 75, 151, paint);
    canvas.drawText("\"Actual\" \u03c0 : 3.1415926535" , 75, 211, paint);
    //canvas.drawText("Error: " + ((piCalculated.divide(pi)).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(1))).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)) + " %",75, 210, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Error: " + errorPercentage, 75, 271, paint);
}

public void calculate() {
    ratio = (double)count / total;
    ratioPercentage = df.format(ratio);
    piCalculated = df1.format(ratio * 4);
    error = Double.parseDouble(piCalculated) / 3.1415926535 - 1;
    errorPercentage = df2.format(error);
    best = mainActivity.getBest();
    if (total > 5000 && Math.abs(error) < best) {
        System.out.println("Evaluate: best update");
        mainActivity.updateBest(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either you're not running the code you think you are (i.e., as posted, the code won't even compile), there's an exception in `calculate`, it turns recursive, or you're not drawing what/where you think you are, etc. In other words, check all your assumptions.

Comment: add System.out.println("something here"); after the call to calculate() to actually see that the code is not executed (if it's not printed, it's not executed). I doubt it will not be executed.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks! Debugging helped to find the error. You were right, there was exception in best = mainActivity.getBest(); in calculate and the thread had catch block. I'll try to fix it but is there way of getting the error code to help fix this?

Comment: @Fra Thanks for the help! It did not execute the rest because there were exception in the code(somehow).

Comment: @Seung Log the exception and stack trace (might already be in the logs) and take it from there.

Comment: @DaveNewton right. best = mainActivity.getBest(); gives the exception, and  it's because mainActivity = null. How do I fix this? I did create  private MainActivity mainActivity; in class.